# How to implement the imageView as developed in fyuse app android?

Tags: android, uiimageview

I am trying to develop a image View which will show the right and left portion on moving it with touch sensor or tilt sensor.
Something Like this : https://fyu.se/v/7fb79f18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AccelerometerActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor accelerometer;
private long lastUpdate;
Bitmap mBitmap1;

// AnimatedView animatedView = null;
//ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
public static int x;
public static int y;
private ImageView imageView;
private int bitmapWidth, screenWidth,screenHeight,bitmapHeight;
int maxxLeft, maxxRight, scrollByX, totalX,totalY,maxTop,maxBottom,scrollByY;
URL url;
String filepath = null;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
int b;

//ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_accelerometer);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AccelerometerActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("loading");

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight=size.y;
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();                                                                                                


    Resources res = getResources();
    Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.panaromic1);
    BitmapDrawable bDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(res, mBitmap);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

    //get the size of the image and  the screen
    bitmapWidth = bDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
    //int bw=mBitmap1.getWidth();
    bitmapHeight = bDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

    Log.v("sw",screenWidth+"");
    Log.v("bw",bitmapWidth+"");
    //Log.v("sw",screenHeight+"");
    //Log.v("bw",bitmapHeight+"");
    int maxX = (int) ((bitmapWidth / 2) - (screenWidth / 2));
   // int maxY = (int) ((bitmapHeight / 2) - (screenHeight / 2));
    maxxLeft = (maxX * -1);
    maxxRight = maxX;
   // maxTop = (maxY * -1);
    //maxBottom = maxY;
}






@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

        //x -= (int) event.values[0];
        //y += (int) event.values[1];
        x = (int) event.values[0];
        y = (int) event.values[1];
        scrollByX = x;
        scrollByY = y;
        if (x > 0) {
            if (totalX == maxxRight) {
                scrollByX = 0;
            }
            if (totalX < maxxRight) {
                totalX = totalX + scrollByX;
            }
            if (totalX > maxxRight) {
                scrollByX = maxxRight - (totalX - scrollByX);
                totalX = maxxRight;
            }
            /*String xx="";
            Log.v("xx:",xx+scrollByX);*/
            imageView.scrollBy(scrollByX, 0);
            /*imageView.scrollBy(5 ,0);*/

        } else {

            if (totalX == maxxLeft) {
                scrollByX = 0;
            }
            if (totalX > maxxLeft) {
                totalX = totalX + scrollByX;
            }
            if (totalX < maxxLeft) {
                scrollByX = maxxLeft - (totalX - scrollByX);
                totalX = maxxLeft;
            }
            imageView.scrollBy(scrollByX, 0);

            }


    }
}

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();

        //pd.show();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mBitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            //b=mBitmap1.getWidth();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mBitmap1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //pd.dismiss();

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me.I put the same code but nothing happens.

Comment: I solved that error. now my question is that how to change the images like fyuse because in your code it only move the image but in fyuse they used sequence of images and move accordingly when move the phone left to right.
so how to do that is it possible? I was up voted your answer.

Comment: In my code its displays the parts which are hidden when you move tilt your mobile based on gravity. In fuse they are actually using too many screens of an image and displaying different on different angle.. IT is possible to do that but i have not implemented because its not possible to get different screens if we are fetching the image from server.

Comment: ya but we can do it using the local images which are exist in the sd card. any idea how to do that?

Comment: For implementing that i suppose first of all you have to read all the value of accelerometer and then based on the values you have to change the frames.